# How to make landscape, threeparttablex, longtable and makecell work together?

Tags: longtable, landscape, makecell, threeparttablex

I am using a `longtable` that expands up to 3 pages in Landscape mode. I have used `makecell`, to insert linebreaks and vertically and horizontaly align the contents in cells. I want to enter footnote in the long table and for that I am using `threeparttablex` package. The problem is when I run below code the `longtable stays` in single page and overflows it. Please help me behave my longtable in regular way and expand to 3 pages instead of overflowing in a single page. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,hidelinks]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace,url,hyperref,array,booktabs,siunitx,textgreek,graphicx,subcaption, lscape, longtable, vcell, pdflscape, mlmodern,tabularx,makecell,threeparttablex}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tl}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{br}
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{TableNotes}
            \item [a] abcd is fun
        \end{TableNotes}
        \begin{longtable}{llllp{3.3 cm}}
            \caption{Summary of metal recovery from spent refining catalysts using hydrometallurgy} \label{hydrometalcompilation} \\[1 ex]
            \toprule
            Methods used &
            Catalyst &
            Optimum conditions &
            Result, \% &
            Reference \\* \midrule
            \endhead
            %
            \bottomrule
            
            \endfoot
            \insertTableNotes
            \endlastfoot
            %
            \makecell{Roasting - \\ acid leaching - \\ solvent extraction} &
            \makecell{Spent \\ hydrogenation \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Roasting:\\ 400 \textsuperscript{o}C, 2 h\\ Leaching:\\ 1 M \ce{H2SO4}, 75 \textsuperscript{o}C, 20 min, \\ S/L = 1/10\\ Mo/V coextraction:\\ 0.3 M TOA + 0.7 M C272, \\ pH = 1\\ Ni extraction:\\ 50\% (v/v) HBL110, pH = 2} &
            \makecell{Leaching efficiency\\ Al = 22.16,\\ Ni = 99.44,\\ Mo = 98.59,\\ V = 100\\ Final products\\ \ce{NiSO4}, \ce{Na2MoO4},\\ \ce{VOSO4} } &
            CHEN2022 \\
            \makecell{Vacuum pyrolysis - \\ roasting - \\ acid leaching} &
            \makecell{Spent \\ hydroprocessing \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Vacuum pyrolysis:\\ 400 \textsuperscript{o}C, 60 min\\ Roasting:\\ 400 \textsuperscript{o}C, 120 min\\ Acid leaching:\\ 1 M \ce{H2SO4}, 45\textsuperscript{o}C, 20 min} &
            \makecell{Leaching efficiency\\ Ni, Mo, V \textgreater 95,\\ Al = 7.63} &
            FENG2022 \\
            \makecell{Calcination - \\ alkali leaching - \\ adsorption - \\ precipitation} &
            \makecell{Spent HDS \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Calcination:\\ 450 \textsuperscript{o}C, 5 h\\ Alkali leaching:\\ 40 g/L \ce{Na2CO3}, 90 \textsuperscript{o}C, 2 h, \\ S/L = 100 g/L} &
            \makecell{Leaching efficiency\\ Mo = 97\\ Final purity\\ \ce{MoO3} = 99.5} &
            KANSOMKET2022 \\
            \makecell{Calcination - alkali \\ leaching - \\ precipitation} &
            \makecell{Spent HDS \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Calcination:\\ 450 \textsuperscript{o}C, 4.5 h\\ Alkali leaching:\\ 20 \% NaOH, 25 \textsuperscript{o}C, 2 h} &
            \makecell{Recovery\\ Mo and V $\sim$ 95\\ Ni = 99\\ Final products\\ \ce{V2O5} and \ce{MoO3}} &
            ROJAS2012 \\
            \makecell{Roasting - oxidative \\ leaching - precipitation} &
            \makecell{Spent HDS \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Roasting:\\ 500 \textsuperscript{o}C, 120 min\\ Leaching:\\ 0.4 M \ce{Na2S2O8}, 50 \textsuperscript{o}C, \\ 90 min, 400 r/min, \\ L/S = 12.5 mL/g, +75–30 μm} &
            \makecell{Recovery\\ Mo = 89.8,\\ Co = 86.5,\\ Ni = 81.2} &
            ARSLANOGLU2021 \\
            \makecell{Roasting - alkali\\leaching} & \makecell{Spent HDS\\catalyst} & \makecell{Roasting:\\600 \textsuperscript{o}C, 60 min\\Leaching:\\0.75 M KOH, 70 \textsuperscript{o}C, 90 min,\\L/S = 15 mL/g, 300 r/min} & \makecell{Extraction yield\\Mo = 93.82,\\Al = 46.91} & YARAS2020 \\
            \makecell{\ce{Na2CO3} assisted \\ roasting - \\ acid leaching - \\ Solvent extraction - \\ precipitation} &
            \makecell{Spent \\ hydrofining \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Roasting:\\ 850 \textsuperscript{o}C, 120\% \ce{Na2CO3}, 2 h\\ Leaching:\\ 2.5 M \ce{H2SO4}, 60 \textsuperscript{o}C, \\ 5\% (w/v), 90 min\\ Mo extraction:\\ 15\% P204 + 3\% TOA, n - heptane, \\ O/A = 1/1, 5 min, pH = 0.65\\ Al extraction:\\ 50\% P204, O/A = 2/1, 20 min\\ Ni precipitation:\\ pH = 7, 140\% \ce{Na2S}, 30 \textsuperscript{o}C, 50 min} &
            \makecell{Recovery\\ Al = 97.5,\\ Mo = 95.5,\\ Mi = 90.9\\ \\ Final forms\\ \ce{MoO3} (pure),\\ \ce{Al(OH)3} (pure),\\ \ce{Ni(OH)S} (pure)} &
            CAI2022 \\
            \makecell{Acid leaching -\\crystallization -\\precipitation} & \makecell{Spent\\reforming\\catalyst} & \makecell{Precipitation:\\0.3 M \ce{H2C2O4}, pH in 1.5 - 2,\\\ce{C2O4^2-}:\ce{Ni^2+} = 2:1, 60 \textsuperscript{o}C, 1 h\\Drying at 110 \textsuperscript{o}C for 4 h\\Decomposition at 600 \textsuperscript{o}C} & \makecell{Recovery\\Ni = 98.5,\\Al = 40.7\tnote{a} \\Final products\\NiO (purity 98.3\%)\\\ce{Al2O3} (purity 99\%)} & abcd 
            \\* \bottomrule
            
        \end{longtable}
        
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{landscape}
    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I would rather use `longtblr` of `tabularray` package.
- Using it the table code is more concise and clear.
- Off-topic:

  - do you really need all packages loaded in preamble?
  - some of them (`\lscape`, `pdflscape`) overwrite each other ...,
  - I suggest you to reconsider, which packages are really needed
  - for all quantities I would use `siunitx` package

MWE, in which I rewrite first few rows (rest of them I left to you), is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,hidelinks]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Summary of metal recovery from spent refining catalysts using hydrometallurgy},
  label = {hydrometalcompilation},
note{a} = {abcd is fun}
                ]{colsep=4pt,
                  colspec = {@{} X[0.9, l,h] *{3}{X[l,h]} l @{} },
                  ROWSEP=3pt,
                  rowhead = 1
                  }
    \toprule
Methods used 
    &   Catalyst 
        &   Optimum conditions 
            &   Result, \% 
                &   Reference                       \\
    \midrule
%
Roasting - acid leaching - solvent extraction
    &   Spent hydrogenation catalyst
        &   {Roasting: \qty{400}{\celsius}, \qty{2}{\hour}\\ 
            Leaching:\\ 
            1 M \ce{H2SO4}, \qty{75}{\celsius}, \qty{20}{\minute}, 
            S/L = 1/10\\ 
            Mo/V coextraction:\\ 
            0.3 M TOA + 0.7 M C272, pH = 1\\ 
            Ni extraction:\\ 
            \qty{50}{\%} (v/v) HBL110, $pH = 2$} 
            &   {Leaching efficiency\\ 
                $\ce{Al} = 22.16$,\\ 
                $\ce{Ni} = 99.44$,\\ 
                $\ce{Mo} = 98.59$,\\ 
                $V = 100$\\ 
                Final products:\\ 
                \ce{NiSO4}, \ce{Na2MoO4}, \ce{VOSO4} } 
                &   CHEN2022                        \\
Vacuum pyrolysis - roasting - acid leaching
    &   Spent hydroprocessing catalyst
        &   {Vacuum pyrolysis:\\ 
            \qty{400}{\celsius}, \qty{60}{\minute}\\ 
            Roasting:\\ 
            \qty{400}{\celsius}, \qty{120}{\minute}\\ 
            Acid leaching:\\ 
            1 M \ce{H2SO4}, \qty{45}{\celsius}, \qty{20}{\minute}}
            &   {Leaching efficiency:\\ 
                \ce{Ni}, \ce{Mo}, $\ce{V}>95$,
                $\ce{Al} = 7.63$} 
                &   FENG2022                        \\
{Calcination - alkali leaching - adsorption - precipitation} 
    &   Spent HDS catalyst
        &   {Calcination:\\ 
            \qty{450}{\celsius}, \qty{5}{\hour}\\ 
            Alkali leaching:\\ 
            \qty{40}{\gram\per\liter} \ce{Na2CO3}, \qty{90}, 
            \qty{2}{\hour}, S/L = \qty{100}{\gram\per\liter}}
            &   {Leaching efficiency\\ 
                $\ce{Mo} = 97$\\ 
                Final purity:\\
                $\ce{MoO3} = 99.5$} 
                    &   KANSOMKET2022               \\
Calcination - alkali leaching - precipitation
    &   Spent HDS  catalyst
        &   {Calcination:\\ 
            \qty{450}{\celsius}, \qty{4.5}{\hour}\\ 
             Alkali leaching:\\ 
             \qty{20}{\%} \ce{NaOH}, \qty{25}{\celsius}, \qty{2}{\hour}} 
             &  {Recovery:\\ 
                \ce{Mo} and \ce{V} $\sim 95$ $\ce{Ni} = 99$\\ 
                Final products; \\
                \ce{V2O5} and \ce{MoO3}} 
                &   ROJAS2012                       \\
Roasting - oxidative leaching - precipitation
    &   Spent HDS catalyst 
        &   {Roasting:\\  \qty{500}{\celsius}, \qty{120}{\minute}\\ 
            Leaching:\\ 
            $0.4 M \ce{Na2S2O8}$, \qty{50}{\celsius}, 
            \qty{90}{\minute}, \qty{400}{r/min}, \\ 
            $L/S = \qty{12.5}{\milli\liter\per\gram}$, \qtyrange{75}{-30}{\micro\meter}}
            &   {Recovery:\\ 
                 $\ce{Mo} = 89.8$, $\ce{Co} = 86.5$, $\ce{Ni} = 81.2$} 
                 &  ARSLANOGLU2021              \\
Roasting - alkali leaching
    &   Spent HDS catalyst
        &   {Roasting:\\
            \qty{600}{\celsius}, \qty{60}{\minute}\\
            Leaching:\\
            0.75 M KOH, \qty{70}{\celsius}, \qty{90}{\minute},\\
            $L/S = \qty{15}{\milli\liter\per\gram}$, \qty{300}{r/min}} 
            &   Extraction yield $\ce{Mo} = 93.82$, $\ce{Al} = 46.91$ 
                &   YARAS2020                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
            \makecell{\ce{Na2CO3} assisted \\ roasting - \\ acid leaching - \\ Solvent extraction - \\ precipitation} &
            \makecell{Spent \\ hydrofining \\ catalyst} &
            \makecell{Roasting:\\ 850 \textsuperscript{o}C, 120\% \ce{Na2CO3}, 2 h\\ Leaching:\\ 2.5 M \ce{H2SO4}, 60 \textsuperscript{o}C, \\ 5\% (w/v), 90 min\\ Mo extraction:\\ 15\% P204 + 3\% TOA, n - heptane, \\ O/A = 1/1, 5 min, pH = 0.65\\ Al extraction:\\ 50\% P204, O/A = 2/1, 20 min\\ Ni precipitation:\\ pH = 7, 140\% \ce{Na2S}, 30 \textsuperscript{o}C, 50 min} &
            \makecell{Recovery\\ Al = 97.5,\\ Mo = 95.5,\\ Mi = 90.9\\ \\ Final forms\\ \ce{MoO3} (pure),\\ \ce{Al(OH)3} (pure),\\ \ce{Ni(OH)S} (pure)} &
            CAI2022 \\
            \makecell{Acid leaching -\\crystallization -\\precipitation} & \makecell{Spent\\reforming\\catalyst} & \makecell{Precipitation:\\0.3 M \ce{H2C2O4}, pH in 1.5 - 2,\\\ce{C2O4^2-}:\ce{Ni^2+} = 2:1, 60 \textsuperscript{o}C, 1 h\\Drying at 110 \textsuperscript{o}C for 4 h\\Decomposition at 600 \textsuperscript{o}C} & \makecell{Recovery\\Ni = 98.5,\\Al = 40.7\tnote{a} \\Final products\\NiO (purity 98.3\%)\\\ce{Al2O3} (purity 99\%)} & abcd
            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What can I do to get table notes appear on pages where they are marked? for example, if I wanted to get a table note on element at intersection of 3st row and 2st column and appear it on the page where it is marked i.e., first page, how can I achieve that?

Comment: @Hemang, this is not straightforward. Actually for this problem  it is worth for ask the new question.

Comment: I have posted [the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687610/how-to-get-table-notes-appear-on-pages-where-they-are-marked-in-tables-panning?noredirect=1#comment1706227_687610)