# How to get table notes appear on pages where they are marked, in tables panning over multiple pages?

Tags: tabularray, tablenotes, longtblr

My table is panning over multiple pages. I placed a marker for a table note on element at intersection of 2nd column, 30th row (assume marker appearing on the second page) and my table note for that marker will show at the end of the table on the last page, instead of that how can I get the table note appear on second page, where it is marked. In general, How can I make table notes appear on the pages they are marked?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,hidelinks]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
        entry = {Short Caption},
        label = {tblr:test},
        note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
        note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
        remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
        remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
        ]{
            colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth,
            rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1
        }
        \hline
        Head & Head & Head \\
        \hline
        Head & Head & Head \\
        \hline
        Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
        \hline
        Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a} & Eta \\
        \hline
        Iota & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
        \hline
        Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
        \hline
        Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
        \hline
        Phi & Chi & Psi \\
        \hline
        .....
        \hline
        Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
        \hline
        Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
        \hline
        Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
        \hline
        Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
        \hline
        Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
        \hline
        Phi & Chi & Psi \\
        \hline
        Foot & Foot & Foot \\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359903/i-have-table-with-long-notes-in-the-longtable-and-threeparttable-environment-h

Comment: Meanwhile solution for `longtable` is known, for `longtblr` so far didn't see it. Probably we need to wait for sam `tabularray` guru or  package author that show us how to do this.